# How to cancel tokio spawn threads from the method calling them

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The test code below considers a situation in which there are three different threads.
Each thread has to do certain asynchronous tasks, that may take a certain time to finish.
This is "simulated" in the code below with a sleep.

On top of that, two of the threads collect information that they have to send to the third one for further processing. This is done using mpsc channels.

Due to the fact that there are out of our control information obtained from outside of the Rust application, the threads may get interrupted. This is emulated by generating a random number, and the loop on each thread breaks when that happens.

What I'm trying to achieve is a system in which whenever one of the threads has an error (simulated with the random number = 9), every other thread is cancelled too.

`

```
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver, TryRecvError};
use std::thread::sleep;
use tokio::time::Duration;
use rand::distributions::{Uniform, Distribution};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    execution_cycle().await;
}


async fn execution_cycle() {
    let (tx_first, rx_first) = channel::<Message>();
    let (tx_second, rx_second) = channel::<Message>();
    let handle_sender_first = tokio::spawn(sender_thread(tx_first));
    let handle_sender_second = tokio::spawn(sender_thread(tx_second));
    let handle_receiver = tokio::spawn(receiver_thread(rx_first, rx_second));

    let mut thread_rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let rng_generator = Uniform::from(1..10);
    let mut cancel_from_cycle = rng_generator.sample(&mut thread_rng);

    while !&handle_sender_first.is_finished() && !&handle_sender_second.is_finished() && !&handle_receiver.is_finished() { 
        cancel_from_cycle = rng_generator.sample(&mut thread_rng);
        if (cancel_from_cycle == 9) {
            println!("Aborting from the execution cycle.");
            handle_receiver.abort();
            handle_sender_first.abort();
            handle_sender_second.abort();
        }
    }

    if handle_sender_first.is_finished() {
        println!("handle_sender_first finished.");
    } else {
        println!("handle_sender_first ongoing.");
    }

    if handle_sender_second.is_finished() {
        println!("handle_sender_second finished.");
    } else {
        println!("handle_sender_second ongoing.");
    }

    if handle_receiver.is_finished() {
        println!("handle_receiver finished.");
    } else {
        println!("handle_receiver ongoing.");
    }
}


async fn sender_thread(tx: Sender<Message>) {
    let mut thread_rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let rng_generator = Uniform::from(1..20);
    let mut random_id = rng_generator.sample(&mut thread_rng);

    while random_id != 9 {
        let msg = Message {
            id: random_id,
            text: "hello".to_owned()
        };
        println!("Sending message {}.", msg.id);
        random_id = rng_generator.sample(&mut thread_rng);
        println!("Generated id {}.", random_id);
        let result = tx.send(msg);
        match result {
            Ok(res) => {},
            Err(error) => {
                println!("Sending error {:?}", error);
                random_id = 9;
            }
        }
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(2000));
    }
}

async fn receiver_thread(rx_first: Receiver<Message>, rx_second: Receiver<Message>) {
    let mut channel_open_first = true;
    let mut channel_open_second = true;
    let mut thread_rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let rng_generator = Uniform::from(1..15);
    let mut random_event = rng_generator.sample(&mut thread_rng);
    while channel_open_first && channel_open_second && random_event != 9 {
        channel_open_first = receiver_inner(&rx_first);
        channel_open_second = receiver_inner(&rx_second);
        random_event = rng_generator.sample(&mut thread_rng);
        println!("Generated event {}.", random_event);
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(800));
    }
}

fn receiver_inner(rx: &Receiver<Message>) -> bool {
    let value = rx.try_recv();
    match value {
        Ok(msg) => {
            println!("Message {} received: {}", msg.id, msg.text);
        },
        Err(error) => { 
            if error != TryRecvError::Empty {
                println!("{}", error);
                return false;
            } else { /* Channel is empty.*/  }                
        }
    }
    return true;
}

struct Message {
    id: usize,
    text: String,
}
```

`

In the working example here, it does exactly that, however, it does it only from inside the threads, and I would like to add a "kill switch" in the execution_cycle() method, allowing to cancel all the three threads when a certain event takes place (the random number cancel_from_cycle == 9), and do that in the most simple way possible... I tried drop(handler_sender), and also panic!() from the execution_cycle() but the spawn threads keep running, preventing the application to finish. I also tried handle_receiver().abort() without success.

How can I achieve the wished result?

Comment: Just use [`abort`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.24.2/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.abort), e.g. `handle_sender_first.abort()`.

Comment: the handler_receiver.abort() inside the while !sender_receiver.is_finished() doesn't work as intended. It does not cancel the thread by any means. The loop keep repeating and spamming "Aborting from the execution cycle." but all threads keep working as if nothing happened.

Comment: Tokio tasks can only be aborted when they `await` something. Don't mix `tokio` and primitives from `std::sync`/`std::thread`. You should use [`tokio::time::sleep`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.24.2/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html) and [`tokio::sync::mpsc::channel`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.24.2/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) which are `await`ed and can therefore be aborted.